# Wordpress 3.2(Multisite) - How to add custom user meta fields to signup form?

Tags: multisite, user-registration, filters

I want to add custom user meta fields to registration page. I use WP multisite so I have to modify `wp-signup.php`.

Adding some field is easy for me(I am programmer :P).

But I have a problem with this line of code:

```
wpmu_signup_user($user_name, $user_email, apply_filters('add_signup_meta', array()));
```

I have searched all Wordpress with bash command:

```
find -name "*" | xargs grep -ni "add_signup_meta"
```

And havent found where exactly is specify `add_filter` for `add_signup_meta`.

Can somebody tell me where exactly `add_signup_meta` filter is located?

Or maybe where is a easier way to add some fields?

WordPress 3.2.1

PS I have tried many plugins for adding custom user fields. Only one is good choice(Cimy User Extra Fields) but unfortunately it doesnt add custom fields for registration(probably this is broken).

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way I know is by using Gravity Forms & [User Registration add-on](http://www.gravityforms.com/add-ons/user-registration/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are probably misunderstanding that line of code. It is essentially telling Wordpress to process any filters accordingly. There are no default functions for the add_signup_meta filter but it has been put there so that we can hook onto it ourselves.

This code might help...

```
<?php 
add_filter('add_signup_meta', 'sb_add_signup_meta');

function sb_add_signup_meta($meta) {
    $meta['mykey'] = 'My Value';

    return $meta;
}
?>
```

This should show you how to hook onto that line and clarify for you that there are actually no default functions for many of the filter references that Wordpress provides us with.

thanks
Sean

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in the past is create my own signup page, and used wp_create_user, add_user_meta, and add_user_to_blog to process the $_POST. You could then throw in wp_mail for new registration if you want. It's pretty quick to make a custom page and gives you full control over the process