# How can I add custom meta on signup page and pass along to be used after blog activation?

Tags: multisite, customization, signup

I am trying to customize a signup process for our MultiSite Network I need to be able to assign levels based on a choice at signup.

My thought is to add a field (hidden or otherwise) that holds the chosen level during signup, and assign that to the registering user somehow, (via meta?) and have that passed along when creating site. I assume there should be a way as their username and email is passed to the database right?

Then when they activate their new site via activation link email, I could run a custom function, (there must be a hook for after site creation) that would grab that meta value I passed along use it in a custom function post activation.

Does this make sense? Thank you for any input!

Comment: Code behind the paywall is considered not in scope here. Please try to make your question more generic - what is happening (in WordPress core terms) and how you are trying to modify it.

Comment: I apologize for that, I edited the question to remove those parts. I am trying to add custom meta on the signup page that can be passed along after activation, and then used in a function after site activation.

Comment: what are you using for your sign up form? custom or default?

Comment: Just the default form

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a very old question, but I had the same issue and this was never resolved so I thought I'd post a solution. I found the answer in a [different topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33925/wordpress-3-2multisite-how-to-add-custom-user-meta-fields-to-signup-form) here on WPSE.

You only have to use the filter [`add_signup_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/add_signup_meta/).

```
function sb_add_signup_meta($meta) {
    // hardcoded value
    $meta['mykey'] = 'My Value';

    // $_POST value from register form
    if ( isset( $_POST[ 'value' ] ) && ! empty( $_POST[ 'value' ] ) ) {
        $meta[ 'meta_key' ] = $_POST[ 'value' ];
    }

    return $meta;
}
add_filter('add_signup_meta', 'sb_add_signup_meta');
```